# What is the force acting on an object inside a spaceship?

Tags: vectors, physics, kinematics

A $7.5$ kg instrument is hanging by a vertical wire inside a spaceship that is blasting off from rest at the earth's surface. This spaceship reaches an altitude of $208 $m in $20$ s with constant acceleration.Find the force that the wire exerts on the instrument.

I have a lot of confusion here.The approach I take to solve the problem seems to be the wrong one according to the solutions I have seen on other forums (yahoo for instance)

**My thought**

The acceleration of the spaceship is given by $\vec{x}=\frac{1}{2}\vec{a} \cdot t^2$, substituting the given values I find $\vec{a}=1.04 \text{ m}/\text{s}^2$ which is positive as I am defining upward to be positive.

So I have that the instrument hanging from a wire is being accelerated at $1.04 \text{ m}/\text{s}^2$. But there is also a opposite acceleration given by $\vec{g}=-9.8 \text{ m}/\text{s}^2$.

Thus I have that the net acceleration of the instrument is given by the vector addition of the corresponding accelerations, i.e. $\vec{a_n}=-8.76 \text{ m}/\text{s}^2$.

So the force acting on the wire is $\vec{F}=m \cdot \vec{a_n}=7.5 \text{ kg} \cdot (-8.76) \text{ m}/\text{s}^2=-65.7\text{ N}$.

As already pointed out,my answer is  apparently wrong because I should have added both accelerations (that means taking both to be positive ,regardless of direction).

The correct solution to this problem is really important for me as I am a self-learner and I don't want to learn false stuff which then I will carry over for the rest of my life .

Comment: Isn't this a physics question?

Comment: I feel that it's more about correct vectors addition of acceleration,that's why I posted it here.Also it's simple kinematics question which I see it's a kind of question that here is accepted (I've looked other questions ).

Comment: People in PhysicsSE are very rude! :) Maybe, that is why you're here. People are so nice here!

Comment: An *inertial* frame is one that is "falling down". Relative to that frame, even a ship at rest is accelerated *up* at 9.81 m/s²

Comment: and yes .Also because physics SE isn't really welcoming as Mathematics SE.lol.Please don't say that to them !Of course I always provide before my effort ,I am not a lazy guy.

Comment: From a physical point of view, it's obvious that the tension in the wire will increase, not decrease, during take-off.

Comment: There are physics people here also i suppose !!

Comment: The high reputation people in the Physics SE are very quick to close and downvote questions without understanding them many a times.

Comment: Maybe I should ask my question about molecular orbitals here! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should draw a free body diagram of the object & consider all the forces acting on that as follows

$\bullet$ **Tension force (T)**: acting upward

$\bullet$ **Gravitational force, $F_g=mg$**: acting downward

$\bullet$ **Inertial force, $F_I=ma$**:  acting downward

Now, balancing all the forces acting on the object, one should get 
$$T=mg+ma$$ $$=m(g+a)$$ $$=7.5(1.04+9.8)$$
$$=\color{red}{81.3\ N}\ (\text{upward})$$
Thus, the tension $T=81.3\ N$ will be the upward force which the wire exerts on the instrument.

Comment: Thanks for writing this all out ! I am really grateful.

Comment: @Winther: Ok, inertial force $F_I$ is assumed to act downward for the dynamic equilibrium of the object under uniform acceleration. It's just an assumption for balancing forces in dynamic equilibrium .  Although, $ma$ is resultant force acting upwards.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the forces acting on the particle alone. There is the tension and the weight of the particle. So using Newton's Law $$\underline{F}=m\underline{a}\Rightarrow T-mg=ma$$

Hence $T=mg+ma$

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's like seeing the sky from a deep well.Give me some time to think about it.

Comment: You're welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Hint always draw a FBD rather than doing mentally. So we have tension acting upwards,gravity acting downwards and ofcourse accn of rocjet upwards so by FBD we have $T=mg+ma$ now we  can use kinematical equations thus $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ . Now use words $$blasted off=u=0$$ thus we get $208=200.a$ so $a=1.04$ so $T=7.5\times 9.8+7.5\times 1.04=81.3N$